# How to compute the gradient for logistic regression in Matlab?

Tags: logistic, matlab

I'm trying to minimize function *f*, firstly I was using **fminsearch** but it works long time, that's why now I use **fminunc**, but there is one problem: I need function gradient for acceleration.

```
f = @(w) sum(log(1 + exp(-t .* (phis * w'))))/size(phis, 1) + coef * w*w';
options = optimset('Display', 'notify', 'MaxFunEvals', 2e+6, 'MaxIter', 2e+6);
w = fminunc(f, ones(1, size(phis, 2)), options);
```

- **phis** size is NxN+1
- **t** size is Nx1
- **coef** is const

Can you help me please construct gradient for function *f*, coz I always get this warning:

```
Warning: Gradient must be provided for trust-region algorithm;
  using line-search algorithm instead.
```

Comment: do you want an implementation in Matlab specifically?

Comment: @suncools - that would be really great, because I'm a newbie in matlab and I can't do this by myself just right now, but I'll appreciate any helpful answers!

Comment: Just for information, this question was originally posted on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080111/) but is more suited here.

Comment: @Yekver, usually logistic regression is solved using [IRWLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares). It involves solving least squares problem in each iteration and it is guaranteed to converge. Why did you not use this method?

Comment: @mpiktas To perform IRLS, you compute the gradient and the Hessian of $f$, and finally apply Newton-Raphson algorithm. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/4vQ9E.png).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gradient should be (by chain rule)

```
%the gradient
%helper function
expt =  @(w)(exp(-t .* (phis * w')));
%precompute -t * phis
tphis = -diag(t) * phis;  %or bsxfun(@times,t,phis);
%the gradient
gradf = @(w)((sum(bsxfun(@times,expt(w) ./ (1 + expt(w)), tphis),1)'/size(phis,1)) + 2*coef * w');
```

probably would be faster not to compute `expt(w)` twice per evaluation, so you can rewrite this in terms of another anonymous function which takes `exptw` as input.

also I may have goofed up the dimensions on the sum--it seems like you are using `w` as a row vector, which is somewhat nonstandard.

**edit**: as @whuber noted, this kind of thing is easy to screw up. I didn't actually try the code I had previously. the above should be correct now. To test it, I estimated the gradient numerically and compared to the 'exact' value, as below:

```
%set up the problem
N = 9;
phis = rand(N,N+1);
t = rand(N,1);
coef = rand(1);

%the objective
f = @(w)((sum(log(1 + exp(-t .* (phis * w'))),1) / size(phis, 1)) + coef * w*w');

%helper function
expt =  @(w)(exp(-t .* (phis * w')));
%precompute -t * phis
tphis = -diag(t) * phis;  %or bsxfun(@times,t,phis);
%the gradient
gradf = @(w)((sum(bsxfun(@times,expt(w) ./ (1 + expt(w)), tphis),1)'/size(phis,1)) + 2*coef * w');

%test the code now:
%compute the approximate gradient numerically
w0 = randn(1,N+1);
fw = f(w0);

%%the numerical:
delta = 1e-6;
eyeN = eye(N+1);

gfw = nan(size(w0));
for iii=1:numel(w0)
    gfw(iii) = (f(w0 + delta * eyeN(iii,:)) - fw) ./ delta;
end

%the 'exact':
truegfw = gradf(w0);

%report
fprintf('max difference between exact and numerical is %g\n',max(abs(truegfw' - gfw)));
```

when I run this (sorry, should have set the rand seed), I get:

`max difference between exact and numerical is 4.80006e-07`

YMMV, depending on the rand seed and the value of `delta` used.

Comment: +1 The real risk with using searches requiring gradients (and Hessians) lies in incorrect coding.  It would be an excellent idea to test out this code thoroughly before applying it (such as by comparing it rigorously to a canned numerical derivative routine), because bugs can be extremely hard to detect later on: if you're unlucky, you will just get slightly bad results without ever knowing it.

Comment: @shabbychef After this `expt(w) ./ (1 + expt(w))` result matrix size is **N+1x1** and size of `tphis` is **NxN+1**. So I get an error while times...
what's wrong?

Comment: @yekver, sorry, I should have tested it. I fixed the code and put in a test script. looks good now.